# Georeferencing from a set of points using lat and long

Tags: arcgis-pro, imagery

I have an image that is 2000x2000 pixels and I need to georeference the image using ArcGIS Pro. I have a text file with lat and long at various pixels:

```
469.4999917 -264.663705 0 E 73 N
504.0687029 -272.9415537    1 E 73 N
538.7881748 -280.6595238    2 E 73 N
573.6478318 -287.8152645    3 E 73 N
608.6370552 -294.4065959    4 E 73 N
643.7451868 -300.4315104    5 E 73 N
678.9615326 -305.8881726    6 E 73 N
714.2753652 -310.7749204    7 E 73 N
749.6759276 -315.0902652    8 E 73 N
785.1524366 -318.8328927    9 E 73 N
820.6940856 -322.0016626    10 E    73 N
856.2900483 -324.5956099    11 E    73 N
891.9294819 -326.6139443    12 E    73 N
927.6015301 -328.056051 13 E    73 N
963.2953271 -328.9214908    14 E    73 N
```

Now I can import these points into ArcGIS, but the coordinates just come in as 0s. Is there a way to import these points and their coordinates and have them read as coordinates?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour]. It's unclear from your problem statement what procedure you have used, and what you expect as a result. Also, you tagged the question with an ancient (and Retired) ArcGIS release that predates Pro; please [Edit] the question to specify the exact Pro release in use.

Comment: Have you tried Make XY Event Layer?